# Geocoder returns nil for ip-addresses?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, geocoding, rails-geocoder

I am working in ruby on rails. Rails version 3.1.1. I have been using [Geocoder](http://www.rubygeocoder.com/) gem to geocode locations based on street addresses and it is working just fine. Now I have been trying to use my visitors ip-address to locate them.

I have tried

```
result = request.location
```

and

```
ip = request.ip
result = Geocoder.search(ip)
```

The first option returns an nil, the second gives me a correct ip-address and an empty array.

Are there any configurations I need to do in order for this to work?

Any other smoother alternatives? I was looking into using HTML5 or some javascript in the browser, but that would not be optimal since I want to use the location on the server side.

Comment: It looks like the IP address you are getting cannot be traced to a specific location. What happens if you type the IP in here: http://whatismyipaddress.com/?gclid=CKWB55rJwK4CFQZ_hwodjDlvug

Comment: I have tried the same IP on a few sites, and they find me. whatismyipaddress.com found me aswell.

Comment: I seem to have the same problem; geocoding by IP did work, but does not work anymore.

Comment: Did not work for me either. I even tried changing the service from FreeGeoIP to Nominatim/Google/Yandex. But no results

Comment: @AlbinSvensson This might be too late to respond, or if you found a different solution, but this is what I've done. In my controller, I created a variable, i.e. like `@client_ip = request.ip`,`@city = request.location.city` and etc and then was able to use those in my views `<%= @city %> and etc.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem this week, the search return null, please take a look at my solution

[error in request.location ruby geocoder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18285240/error-in-request-location-ruby-geocoder)

The solution was increment the timeout.